# How to install [ gcc ] without internet connection?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, gcc, repository

I simply ran

```
 yum install gcc
```

this is what came up:

```
================================================================================
     Package             Arch        Version                     Repository    Size
    ================================================================================
    Installing:
     gcc                 x86_64      4.4.7-3.el6                 base          10 M
    Installing for dependencies:
     cloog-ppl           x86_64      0.15.7-1.2.el6              base          93 k
     cpp                 x86_64      4.4.7-3.el6                 base         3.7 M
     glibc-devel         x86_64      2.12-1.107.el6_4.4          updates      974 k
     glibc-headers       x86_64      2.12-1.107.el6_4.4          updates      605 k
     kernel-headers      x86_64      2.6.32-358.18.1.el6         updates      2.3 M
     mpfr                x86_64      2.4.1-6.el6                 base         157 k
     ppl                 x86_64      0.10.2-11.el6               base         1.3 M
    Updating for dependencies:
     glibc               x86_64      2.12-1.107.el6_4.4          updates      3.8 M
     glibc-common        x86_64      2.12-1.107.el6_4.4          updates       14 M

    Transaction Summary
    ================================================================================
    Install       8 Package(s)
    Upgrade       2 Package(s)

    Total download size: 37 M
    Is this ok [y/N]: n
```

so i ran

```
repoquery --location
```

on each one of those items. and got their downloadable url.

i simply created a new folder and then downloaded all these files like this.

```
# wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirror.wiredtree.com/centos/6.4/os/x86_64/Packages/ppl-0.10.2-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirror.wiredtree.com/centos/6.4/os/x86_64/Packages/mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirror.wiredtree.com/centos/6.4/os/x86_64/Packages/cpp-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirror.wiredtree.com/centos/6.4/os/x86_64/Packages/cloog-ppl-0.15.7-1.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
# wget http://mirror.wiredtree.com/centos/6.4/os/x86_64/Packages/gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

but it appears they were not in any particular order by the

```
yum install gcc
```

so i started installing some of them but i got stuck.

```
rpm -ivh mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh cpp-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh ppl-0.10.2-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh cloog-ppl-0.15.7-1.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
#
rpm -ivh glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

in other words everything was installed fine ( i sorted them out based on what was installed without problems.

right under `#` is where the problems start.

i can not run anything after the # because nothing is installing after that line.

what should i do ?

## UPDATE

they are failing after the #
because.. the first one depends on the second one
and second one depends on the first one.

in other words..

```
rpm -ivh glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
```

is asking for

```
rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64.rpm
```

while that one is asking for the first one again.

Comment: Well, to start with, edit into your question the exact output from the command immediately before things started failing, and from a failing `rpm -ivh` command. "I cannot run anything" and "nothing is installing" doesn't say much about what might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `yum` to do the installation too.

```
$ yum --nogpgcheck localinstall *.rpm
```

Yum will then make sure that the dependencies are all set before attempting to install. It will even look into the proposed .rpm files you're attempting to install to make sure that their dependencies are satisfied.

In general it's usually a bad idea to attempt to install multiple .rpm files using single `rpm -ivh ...`. Better to include them all on one command line so that `rpm` can check the dependencies across the entire set of .rpms too.